# How to replace Hash Match with Merged Join?

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm learning how SQL Server join operations works and I'm working on Adventure Works 2017 db.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
   e.JobTitle, a.City,
   p.LastName + ', ' + p.FirstName AS EmployeeName
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS bea
   ON e.BusinessEntityID = bea.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Person.Address AS a
   ON bea.AddressID = a.AddressID
INNER JOIN Person.Person AS p
   ON e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
```

Execution plan:

[image: Execution plan]

My question is what can I do to replace Hash Match operation with Merged Join?

Comment: Why do you want to do so? Plan operators are chosen based on the estimated best performance, is threre any specific problem you want to solve with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a [hint for a particular join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-join) in a query:

```sql
INNER merge JOIN Person.Address AS a ON bea.AddressID = a.AddressID
```

Keep in mind that, in SQL Server, hints are considered measures of a last resort. It's much better to look at [missing indices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-missing-index-group-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and / or [index fragmentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) levels before nailing a hint into a query.

Comment: I thought about adding index. Which index should I add in this specific case?

Comment: @piter12, in this particular case the query already uses an index on the `Person.Address` table, so there's little to do on this side. Truth be told, I thought you had a purely academical interest, because merge joins are usually efficient only with large datasets on both sides. These tables look pretty small, so performance will probably worsen, not improve.

Comment: I have academical interest, my goal is not to improve performance, but learn how join operation works. So what should I do to replace hash match with merged join?

Comment: @piter12, look for the word "merge" in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `OPTION(MERGE JOIN)` query hint to help coerce merge join operators. Note that this will also introduce sort operators in cases where a suitable index does not exist to provide ordering needed for the merge join operator so performance with the hint may be worse than without.

```
SELECT 
   e.JobTitle, a.City,
   p.LastName + ', ' + p.FirstName AS EmployeeName
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS bea
   ON e.BusinessEntityID = bea.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Person.Address AS a
   ON bea.AddressID = a.AddressID
INNER JOIN Person.Person AS p
   ON e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
OPTION(MERGE JOIN);
```

Comment: I don't want to replace all joins, but only hash match. Nested loops should be untouched.